# Single selection checkbox

Tags: c#, loops, input, knockout.js, onclick

I want to only allow a single checkbox to be selected inside my foreach loop, right now I can select multiple.I have a click event but this will not uncheck the other checkboxes when I make a checkbox selection. What's wrong here? Thanks

```
<div class="consulting-editors" data-bind="foreach: ConsultingEditors">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Promote" data-bind="checked: Promote, click: $parent.promoterSelectedOnclick" /> Display as main editor 
</div>

ConsultingEditors: KnockoutObservableArray<NavigatorAuthorApi> = ko.observableArray();  

promoterSelectedOnclick = (selectedEditor: NavigatorAuthorApi) => {

    if (this.ConsultingEditors().some(e => e.Promote)) {
        this.ConsultingEditors().filter(e => e.AuthorRef != selectedEditor.AuthorRef).forEach((e) => {
            e.Promote = false;
        });
    }

    return this.ConsultingEditors();
}

export type NavigatorAuthorApi =
    {
        SortOrder: number,
        FirmRef: number,
        FirmName: string,
        AuthorRef: number,
        AuthorName: string,
        DisplayString: string,
        EditorImage: ByteString[],
        Promote: boolean
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes?

Comment: I need to deselect

Answer (score 0):

`Promote` should be an `observable` if you want property change to reflect on the DOM.

```js
class viewModel {

  ConsultingEditors = ko.observableArray([
    { Promote: ko.observable(false), AuthorRef: 1},
    { Promote: ko.observable(false), AuthorRef: 2 },
    { Promote: ko.observable(false), AuthorRef: 3 }
  ]);

  promoterSelectedOnclick = (selectedEditor) => {
    this.ConsultingEditors().filter(e => e.AuthorRef != selectedEditor.AuthorRef).forEach((e) => {
      e.Promote(false);
    });
    return true;
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="consulting-editors" data-bind="foreach: ConsultingEditors">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Promote" data-bind="checked: Promote, click: $parent.promoterSelectedOnclick" /> Display
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

1. You need your click function to return `true` otherwise the click binding will conflict with the checked binding.
2. Promote is being used as a boolean, but it needs to be an Observable for the UI to react to any changes to its value. Everything that the UI needs to react to has to be a knockout observable.

```js
function viewModel(){
    var self=this;

    self.ConsultingEditors = ko.observableArray([
     new NavigatorAuthorApi(false, 1),
      new NavigatorAuthorApi(false, 2),
      new NavigatorAuthorApi(false, 3)
    ]);

    self.promoterSelectedOnclick = function(selectedEditor){
        if (self.ConsultingEditors().some(e => e.Promote())) {
            var others = self.ConsultingEditors().filter(e => e.AuthorRef != selectedEditor.AuthorRef);
            others.forEach((e) => {
                e.Promote(false);
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
}

function NavigatorAuthorApi(promote, authorRef)
{
  var self = this;
   self.SortOrder = null;
    self.FirmRef = null;
    self.FirmName = null;
    self.AuthorRef = authorRef;
    self.AuthorName = null;
    self.DisplayString = null;
    self.EditorImage = null;
    self.Promote = ko.observable(promote);
}   
    
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="consulting-editors" data-bind="foreach: ConsultingEditors">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Promote" data-bind="checked: Promote, click: $parent.promoterSelectedOnclick" /> Display as main editor 
</div>
```